# Link multiple chart controls in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On my web page i'm displaying 5 different line charts with a zoomable X axis. Each chart also has a number of series that are the same for all the charts.

Im looking for the the controls where you can show/hide a series and zoom feature to happen within each graph no matter which graphs controls I change.

Is this something Highcharts support?

Answer (score 6):

Please familiar with example which synchronizes three charts and have unzoom button.

```
$(function() {
var chart1;
    var chart2;
    var chart3;
    var controllingChart;

    var defaultTickInterval = 5;
    var currentTickInterval = defaultTickInterval;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        function unzoom() {
             chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
             chart2.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
             chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = false;

            chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
            chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
            chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
        }

        //catch mousemove event and have all 3 charts' crosshairs move along indicated values on x axis

        function syncronizeCrossHairs(chart) {
            var container = $(chart.container),
                offset = container.offset(),
                x, y, isInside, report;

            container.mousemove(function(evt) {

                x = evt.clientX - chart.plotLeft - offset.left;
                y = evt.clientY - chart.plotTop - offset.top;
                var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
                //remove old plot line and draw new plot line (crosshair) for this chart
                var xAxis1 = chart1.xAxis[0];
                xAxis1.removePlotLine("myPlotLineId");
                xAxis1.addPlotLine({
                    value: chart.xAxis[0].translate(x, true),
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'red',
                    //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                    id: "myPlotLineId"
                });
                //remove old crosshair and draw new crosshair on chart2
                var xAxis2 = chart2.xAxis[0];
                xAxis2.removePlotLine("myPlotLineId");
                xAxis2.addPlotLine({
                    value: chart.xAxis[0].translate(x, true),
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'red',
                    //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                    id: "myPlotLineId"
                });

                var xAxis3 = chart3.xAxis[0];
                xAxis3.removePlotLine("myPlotLineId");
                xAxis3.addPlotLine({
                    value: chart.xAxis[0].translate(x, true),
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'red',
                    //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                    id: "myPlotLineId"
                });

                //if you have other charts that need to be syncronized - update their crosshair (plot line) in the same way in this function.                   
            });
        }

         //compute a reasonable tick interval given the zoom range -
    //have to compute this since we set the tickIntervals in order
    //to get predictable synchronization between 3 charts with
    //different data.
    function computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax) {
        var zoomRange = xMax - xMin;

        if (zoomRange <= 2)
            currentTickInterval = 0.5;
        if (zoomRange < 20)
            currentTickInterval = 1;
        else if (zoomRange < 100)
            currentTickInterval = 5;
    }

    //explicitly set the tickInterval for the 3 charts - based on
    //selected range
    function setTickInterval(event) {
        var xMin = event.xAxis[0].min;
        var xMax = event.xAxis[0].max;
        computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);

        chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = currentTickInterval;
        chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
        chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = currentTickInterval;
        chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
        chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = currentTickInterval;
        chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
    }

    //reset the extremes and the tickInterval to default values
    function unzoom() {
        chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = defaultTickInterval;
        chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
        chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = defaultTickInterval;
        chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
        chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = defaultTickInterval;
        chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;

        chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
        chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
        chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);
    }

            $(document).ready(function() {


                $('#btn').click(function(){
                    unzoom();
                });

                var myPlotLineId = "myPlotLine";
                chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        //x axis only
                        borderColor: '#003399',
                        //'#022455',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        isZoomed:false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Height Versus Weight'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: Notional Test Data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            enabled: true,
                            text: 'Height (cm)'
                        },
                        tickInterval:5,
                        startOnTick: true,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        showLastLabel: true,
                        events:{

                            afterSetExtremes:function(){

                                 if (!this.chart.options.chart.isZoomed)
                                 {                                         
                                    var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                                    var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;

                                    var zmRange = computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval =zmRange;
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;

                                   chart2.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                   chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                   chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);

                                    chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                                      chart2.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                                   chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Weight (kg)'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '' + this.x + ' km, ' + this.y + ' km';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 70,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        scatter: {
                            marker: {
                                radius: 5,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Group 1',
                        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                        data: [[146.2, 51.6], [147.5, 59.0], [148.5, 49.2], [151.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                                                                                [157.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [161.0, 69.8], [166.2, 66.8], [168.2, 75.2],
                                                                                [172.5, 55.2], [174.9, 54.2], [176.9, 62.5], [180.4, 42.0], [190.0, 50.0]]

                        },
                    {
                        name: 'dummy_data',
                        //put this in so that x axis is consistent between 3 charts to begin with
                        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
                        showInLegend: false,
                        data: [[145.0, 0.0], [200.0, 0.0]]}]

                }, function(chart) { //add this function to the chart definition to get synchronized crosshairs
                    syncronizeCrossHairs(chart);
                });

                chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container2',
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        //x axis only
                        borderColor: '#003399',
                        //'#022455',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        isZoomed:false
                        /*events: {
                            selection: function(event) { //this function should zoom chart1, chart2, chart3 according to selected range
                                controllingChart = "chart2";
                                setTickInterval(event);
                            }
                        }*/
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Height Versus Weight'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: Notional Test Data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            enabled: true,
                            text: 'Height (cm)'
                        },
                        tickInterval:5,
                        startOnTick: true,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        showLastLabel: true,
                        events: {
                            afterSetExtremes: function() {
                                if (!this.chart.options.chart.isZoomed) 
                                {
                                    var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                                    var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
                                    var zmRange = computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval =zmRange;
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;


                                   chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                   chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);

                                    chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                                     chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                                   chart3.options.chart.isZoomed = false;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Weight (kg)'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '' + this.x + ' km, ' + this.y + ' km';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 70,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        scatter: {
                            marker: {
                                radius: 5,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'dummy_data',
                        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                        showInLegend: false,
                        data: [[145.0, 0.0], [200.0, 0.0]]},
                    {
                        name: 'Group 2',
                        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
                        data: [[151.0, 65.6], [166.3, 71.8], [167.5, 80.7], [168.5, 72.6], [172.2, 78.8],
                                                                                                    [174.5, 74.8], [175.0, 86.4], [181.5, 78.4], [182.0, 62.0], [184.0, 81.6],
                                                                                                    [185.0, 76.6], [186.8, 83.6], [186.0, 90.0], [188.0, 74.6], [190.0, 71.0],
                                                                                                    [192.0, 79.6], [193.7, 93.8], [196.5, 70.0], [199.0, 72.4]]}]
                }, function(chart) { //add this function to the chart definition to get synchronized crosshairs
                    //this function needs to be added to each syncronized chart 
                    syncronizeCrossHairs(chart);

                });

                chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container3',
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        //x axis only
                        borderColor: '#003399',
                        //'#022455',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        isZoomed:false
                        /*events: {
                            selection: function(event) { //this function should zoom chart1, chart2, chart3
                                controllingChart = "chart3";
                                setTickInterval(event);
                            }
                        }*/
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Height Versus Weight'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: Notional Test Data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            enabled: true,
                            text: 'Height (cm)'
                        },
                        tickInterval:5,
                        startOnTick: true,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        showLastLabel: true,
                        events: {
                             afterSetExtremes: function() {
                                 if (!this.chart.options.chart.isZoomed) {
                                    var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                                    var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
                                    var zmRange = computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval =zmRange;
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval = zmRange;
                                    chart3.xAxis[0].isDirty = true; 

                                   chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                   chart2.options.chart.isZoomed = true;
                                   chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);

                                   chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                                     chart1.options.chart.isZoomed = false;
                                   chart2.options.chart.isZoomed = false;

                                }
                    }
                            }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Weight (kg)'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '' + this.x + ' km, ' + this.y + ' km';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 70,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        scatter: {
                            marker: {
                                radius: 5,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'dummy_data',
                        //I put this in to try to get the charts to have the same range on the x axis
                        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                        showInLegend: false,
                        data: [[145.0, 0.0], [200.0, 0.0]]},
                    {
                        name: 'Group 3',
                        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
                        data: [[153.0, 65.6], [156.3, 71.8], [167.5, 80.7], [169.5, 72.6], [171.2, 78.8],
                                                                                                    [172.5, 74.8], [177.0, 86.4], [181.5, 78.4], [183.0, 62.0], [184.0, 81.6],
                                                                                                    [185.0, 76.6], [186.2, 83.6], [187.0, 90.0], [188.7, 74.6], [190.0, 71.0],
                                                                                                    [192.0, 79.6], [195.7, 93.8], [196.5, 70.0], [199.4, 72.4]]}]
                }, function(chart) { //add this function to the chart definition to get synchronized crosshairs
                    //this function needs to be added to each syncronized chart 
                    syncronizeCrossHairs(chart);

                });


            });

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/27/

Comment: That is very close to what I need thanks! Any idea on how to get the event for when the "Group 1" or "Group 2" buttons are clicked. Once I find that out I can call the enable/disable series by ID in each chart to link all the buttons.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for also, but my xAxis is datetime. Will the computeTickInterval and setTickInterval functions work with datetime format? I have 4 charts to sync but the dates of all charts are identical. btw, awesome job with the above jsfiddle. Very slick

Comment: @geomajor56 certainly it will work, it is only other format of xAxis. So take look at setExtremes function (to define correct ranges) and that's all.

Comment: Hello @SebastianBochan , the sample is great .. it is exactly what i want. but is there anyway to not show the 'red line' as Plot and use the chart's default crosshair instead ? Thank you

Comment: Nope, you can use only a path rendered. But in my example you can add horizontal line by edit path.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

The easiest option would be to show/hide and zoom with extra buttons.
So you would add some buttons to your page and execute a function like:

//Edit made a mistake selecting the chart:

You should create your chart and add it to the Array when you are creating it. For example:

```
var charts = new Array(); 
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(opts);
charts.push(chart);
```

Then for the function:

```
//Set xAxis extremes (zoom)
for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
        charts[i].xAxis[0].setExtremes(startDate, endDate);
}
```

to change the zoom.
Showing and hiding of a series is also pretty simple:

[Highstock Options Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.hide%28%29)

So you could just call `charts[i].series[0].hide();` to hide the first Series

Another possibility would be to use the Highcharts events to start a similar function when a user clicks on the chart.

For example on the legend: [Highstock Options Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.events.legendItemClick)

And for the Zoom:

```
xAxis : {
     events : {
        afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes
    },
},
```