# Possible to connect the zoom on two Highcharts graphs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a line graph and an area graph from the Highcharts API on my page that are x zoom-able like so:

```
chart: {
   type: 'line',
   zoomType: 'x'
}
```

Is it possible to make it so if I zoom in on one graph, it will apply the same zoom to the other graph? And vice versa?

I've looked online and in the API and I can't find anything but I feel like it should be possible.

Comment: Found this that appears to do what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983931/link-multiple-chart-controls-in-highcharts

Comment: Yikes, that looks long-winded. So I take it that it's not part of the API?

Comment: Not directly. But since it is accessible via jQuery it should work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fiddle helped figure it out:

[jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/27/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/27/)

It basically overwrites the `setExtremes` method with a custom one to propagate the event to the other graphs.

```
 events:{
    afterSetExtremes:function(){
      ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Highcharts is pretty cool.

You could send in a function doing something like this:
`function setExtremes() {
            var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
            var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
            vm.chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
            vm.chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
            vm.chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
        }`
... Added bonus: even panning accross charts is supported in this way.